# Implementing Pagination in ASP.NET Core project with MongoDB.Driver - 'Method not found' error troubleshooting

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, swagger

I wanna make a GetPage in my project, however, I have the following mistake:

> `Method not found: 'MongoDB.Driver.PipelineStageDefinition`2<!!0,!!0>
> MongoDB.Driver.PipelineStageDefinitionBuilder.Skip(Int32)'.`

My Controller:

```
[Route("GetPage")]
        [HttpPut]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetPage([FromQuery]int page,[FromQuery] int limit, GetPage request)
        {
            try
            {
                var command = new GetPageCharger { Model = request, PageNumber= page, PageSize=limit };
                return Ok(await Mediator.Send(command));
            }catch(Exception ex)
            {
                return BadRequest($"eror {ex.Message}");
            }
        }
```

My command:

```
public class GetPageCharger : IRequest<PageResult<ChargerModelResponse>>
    {
        public GetPage Model { get; set; }
        public int PageNumber { get; set; }
        public int PageSize { get; set; }
    }

    public class GetPageChargerHandler : IRequestHandler<GetPageCharger, PageResult<ChargerModelResponse>>
    {
        private readonly IChargerRepository _repository;
        private readonly IMapper _mapper;

        public GetPageChargerHandler(IChargerRepository repository)
        {
            _repository = repository;

            var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.CreateMap<Entities.Charger, ChargerModelResponse>()
                     .ForMember(dest => dest.CharginPowerId, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.CharginPower.Id))
                    .ForMember(dest => dest.CharginPowerDescription, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.CharginPower.Description))
                    .ForMember(dest => dest.ConnectorTypeId, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ConnectorType.Id))
                    .ForMember(dest => dest.ConnectorTypeDescription, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ConnectorType.Description))
                    .ForMember(dest => dest.ChargerBrandId, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ChargerBrand.Id))
                    .ForMember(dest => dest.LocationAddress, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.LocationAddress))
                    .ForMember(dest => dest.Latitude, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Latitude))
                    .ForMember(dest => dest.Longitude, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Logitude))
                    .ForMember(dest => dest.PlaceId, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.PlaceId))
                    
                    .ForMember(dest => dest.ChargerBrandDescription, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ChargerBrand.Description))
                    .ForMember(dest => dest.EnergySupplyCompanyId, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.EnergySupplyCompany.Id))
                    .ForMember(dest => dest.EnergySupplyCompanyDescription, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.EnergySupplyCompany.Description))
                    .ForMember(dest => dest.PricingId, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Pricing.Id))
                    .ForMember(dest => dest.ImagesLinks, opt => opt.MapFrom(MapImagesLinks))
                    .ForMember(dest => dest.PricingDescription, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Pricing.Description));
                cfg.CreateMap<WeVeAdmin.Entities.Availability, AvailabilityModel>().ReverseMap();
                cfg.CreateMap<WeVeAdmin.Entities.AvailabilityOnTheDay, AvailabilityOnTheDayModel>().ReverseMap();
                cfg.CreateMap<WeVeAdmin.Entities.AvailabilityHours, AvailabilityHoursModel>().ReverseMap();
            });
            _mapper = config.CreateMapper();
        }
        public async Task<PageResult<ChargerModelResponse>> Handle(GetPageCharger request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var (results, pageCount, totalCount) = await _repository.GetPage(
              request.Model.PropertyToSortBy,
              (SortOrder)request.Model.SortOrder,
              request.PageNumber,
              request.PageSize);

            var pageResult = new PageResult<ChargerModelResponse>(
                _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Entities.Charger>, IReadOnlyCollection<ChargerModelResponse>>(results), pageCount, totalCount);

            return pageResult;

        }
        private List<string>? MapImagesLinks(WeVeAdmin.Entities.Charger charger, ChargerModelResponse chargerResponse)
        {
            var result = new List<string>();
            if (charger.ImagesDescriptions == null) { return null; }

            foreach (var item in charger.ImagesDescriptions)
            {
                result.Add(item);
            }
            return result;
        }
```

The GetPage's repository:

```
 

    Task<(IReadOnlyList<TEntity> results, long pageCount, long totalCount)> GetPage(
                string propertyToSortBy, SortOrder sortOrder, int pageNumber, int pageSize);
```

And GetPage Model:

```
public string PropertyToSortBy { get; set; }
        public int SortOrder { get; set; }
```

I tried to make foreachs, new methods and more but I stil I don't know why happen that.

Comment: Could you please double check if all the required dependencies has been installed accrodingly.